# How to create scenes in Godot so their front is in view when opening a scene

Tags: godot

From my understanding in Godot "forward" means looking towards -Z. Both for the camera and any scenes (spatial nodes).
That means in order for your objects to work correctly with the `look_at()` method you should build them like that from the start.

But if I create all the scenes with -Z as the forward vector then whenever I open the scene the camera is positioned and rotated in such a way that I'm viewing the back of the object.

I'd like to have a front view of a scene whenever I open it so I'm thinking I can either:

- Create the scenes with the front being the back (I feel like this will bring a long a lot of headaches in the long run)
- Move the camera automatically with an EditorPlugin so when I open a scene I actually see the front of the scene.

I actually tried the second idea but if I move the editor's camera, Godot snaps it back to the previous position, which makes me think that the editor is controlling the camera's position.

I was wondering how everyone else handles this...

Comment: We… Hmm… Don't bother? Godot remembers the position you left the editor camera and restores it when you open the scene. This experience of always opening the scene to look at from the back is alien to me.

Comment: Does it? It never happens for me... Whenever I open a scene the camera resets to it's default position.

Comment: I does. Both on tscn and scn. I tried it before posting that comment, and again right now. Could be a platform/version thing? I'm on Windows 10, and I remember this behavior at least since Godot 3.2. I'm not sure before. Edit: If not that, some module or addon would be my next guess.

Comment: Ok, something occurred to me, perhaps you are opening a model (e.g. a gltf), and you never save it as Godot scene. You use it directly. In that case, yeah, it does not save your editor camera position, it always resets.

Comment: Oh it seems that if I save the scene after moving the camera it remembers it.
I thought I tested this and didn't work. Guess my bad.

Thanks a lot for the help!